# Check like fanpage with php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I have application create cover game Leaguage of legend in facebook. This is my source code to check like fanpage

```
$likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/691865667544259");
if( !empty($likes['data']) ) 
   $like = true;
else
   $like= false;
if($like == false){  
   echo "<img style='margin-left:220px' src='img/like.png'/>";
}
```

But have some users encountering errors-

[image: this is iamge errors].

Why have users encountering errors but have not encountered errors and how to fix this?

Comment: What's the error? The screenshot is not in English! :-/

Comment: Your screenshot shows a page tab app … and inside those, you do not even need to ask or `user_likes` permission and question the API, because you will get that info within the `signed_request` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As per v2.0 Facebook API changes, your application is no longer able to ask for permissions on anything besides public_profile, email and user_friends without first being reviewed by Facebook.

Please, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login for extended information about the Login Review process.